# Problem using async functions in NodeJs middleware

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am running into an issue when I try to load the initial data for my blacklist from a Redis DB in my middleware code. Since the DB request takes some time it starts to fail.

Below is my code which gets fired when app starts via `app.use(blacklist.blockRequests());`.

When I try to make the function async I get the error that `new TypeError('app.use() requires a middleware function')`.

One of the side effects is also that my array is empty when it's called again.

```
blockRequests: function() {
  this.read();
  this.logEvent('info', 'There are ' + this.blacklist.length + ' address(es) on the blacklist');
  var self = this;

  var interceptor = function(request, response, next) {
    var ip = request.headers['x-forwarded-for'] || request.connection.remoteAddress;

    if (self.isInBlacklist(ip)) {
      self.logEvent('warn', 'Rejecting request from ' + ip + ', path and query was ' + request.originalUrl);
      response.status(403).send();
    } else {
      next();
    }
  }

  return interceptor;
},
```

And here is my `read()` function code:

```
read: function() {
  try {
    // get all records with prefix block:: from redis
    redis.redis.keys('block::*', function (err, reply) {
      // reply is null when the key is missing
      if(err){}
      else {
        this.blacklist = []

        for (let i = 0; i < reply.length; i++) {
          let ipInt = reply[i].substring(7)
          let ipStr = ipToInt(ipInt).toIP()
          this.blacklist.push(ipStr)             
        }
      }   
    });
  } catch (error) {
    if (error) {
      this.blacklist = [];
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: when i try to do blockRequests: async() => { i get the error that the middleware requires function. The current code right now loads but does not work since the blacklist array is always empty when called subsequently

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're trying to make `blockRequests()` async, then it will start returning a promise and you can't use its return value directly in `app.use()`.  Because then you'd be doing `app.use(somePromise)` and Express will balk because you have to pass it a function reference, not a promise.

Instead, you will have to use `.then()` or `await` to get the return value which is the function which you could then use with `app.use()`.

If you show the larger calling context here (like where you're calling `blockRequests()` from), then we could offer more ideas on a fuller solution.

Here's a conceptual idea for how you could do this:

```
blockRequests: function() {
  const self = this;
  const interceptor = function(request, response, next) {
    const ip = request.headers['x-forwarded-for'] || request.connection.remoteAddress;

    if (self.isInBlacklist(ip)) {
      self.logEvent('warn', 'Rejecting request from ' + ip + ', path and query was ' + request.originalUrl);
      response.status(403).send();
    } else {
      next();
    }
  }
  return interceptor;
},

read: function() {
    // get all records with prefix block:: from redis
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        redis.redis.keys('block::*', (err, reply) => {
            if (err) {
                this.blacklist = [];
                reject(err);
            } else {
                this.blacklist = [];
        
                for (let i = 0; i < reply.length; i++) {
                  let ipInt = reply[i].substring(7)
                  let ipStr = ipToInt(ipInt).toIP()
                  this.blacklist.push(ipStr)             
                }
            }
            this.logEvent('info', 'There are ' + this.blacklist.length + ' address(es) on the blacklist');
            resolve();
        });
    });
}


// register middleware for using blacklist
app.use(blacklist.blockRequests());

// now read the blacklist and when that is in place, then start the server
blacklist.read().then(() => {
   // now we know that blacklist.blacklist is up-to-date

   // start your server here

}).catch(err => {
   console.log("Unable to start server - error in reading blacklist");
   process.exit(1);
});
```

Comment: i only call it once in the index file app.use(blacklist.blockRequests()) which has the function to go and load the blacklisted ip's from a redis server and then put them into a local array. And since this tkes longer and i cant use the await to wait for the data to be read i am getting the issues while loading data.

Comment: @MisterniceGuy - Well, here's the challenge with a solution.  You have an asynchronous redis call that you NEED the answer to before you can properly start your server because you need the blacklist to be in place before your server starts.  So, you will have to get that info, the call your `app.use()` BEFORE you call `app.listen()` or however it is you start your server.  You don't show enough of your overall structure of how you initialize and start your server for us to show you how this would/could fit into that.

Comment: @MisterniceGuy - I updated my answer with a concept for how you could solve this.

Comment: Thanks, but i am still faced with the same issue, when i load the data in the read function to the array i can see the data in the array as expected. But when i then call a function which checks if an ip is in the array, the array is empty. So not sure why it loses the data

Comment: Just some more insight if i just call this.blacklist.push('192.168.1.34') and this.blacklist.push('192.168.1.36') instead of the for loop the data is in the array and stays

Comment: @MisterniceGuy - Probably you're looking at the data in the array BEFORE the asynchronous operation has completed and has put the data in the array.  Put a `console.log()` in the part of the function that inserts data into the array and put a separate `console.log()` in the code that looks at the array and you will probably see that you're looking in the array before the data has been added.  Please reread my answer and try to really understand what it's doing because it makes a lot of effort to not use the data until the read operation has completed.

Comment: Thats not the case, i have aconsole.log at the end of the loop and it shows the the data is in the array, then if i call the function that checks if data is in array and log the array its empty. Even if i call the functions several sec after.

Comment: @MisterniceGuy - You're not understanding what I'm asking you to do.  Of course, the data is in there at the end of the synchronous loop where you put it in.  Put a `console.log()` there AND another one where you say the data isn't there and see which `console.log()` comes first.  You will be surprised.

Comment: you missing my point, the first console.log is after the loop finishes, then the second console.log is when i call the function after a few seconds after the lop finished. So logically the log of the finished loop is before the log with empty array when i call the function

Comment: @MisterniceGuy - Please add to your question (at the end, do not remove the existing part of the question) the EXACT code that you say contains these `console.log()` statements and show exactly what the logs show.  I can't follow from text what code you're running so can't help any further unless I can see the actual code.  Also, I proposed a different code structure in my answer than your original code so I have no idea if you're using that or not.

Comment: @MisterniceGuy - And, oh by the way, probably where you're getting confused is when you say ***"a few seconds after the loop finishes.  So logically, the log of the finished loop is before the log with the empty array when I call the function"***.  This is exactly where people get confused with asynchronous operations.  Just because your function returned and the caller executed some more code after the function returned does NOT mean that the non-blocking, asynchronous code inside that function is done yet.  That's a classic error of asynchronous programming.

Comment: i thought to fix that issue we have blacklist.read().then() which i am under the impression does not execute anything inside the {} untill our read() is resolved. What am i missing ? Or how can i tell if the async function is completed ?

Comment: @MisterniceGuy - I can't comment on code I can't see.  If you want to ask a follow-on question, then please be very specific about what code you're asking about and if that code is not already shown somewhere that you can point me to, you have to show it to me before I can comment on it.  `blacklist.read().then()` will work the way you describe if and only if the internals of the `.read()` function are written correctly.

Comment: To make it simpler i put the relevant code up on repl.it https://repl.it/@NoSoup4you2/BlackList , If you start it and hit refresh you will see what i am talking

Comment: @MisterniceGuy - Props to you for putting it into something I could run and debug.  The problem was that the callback in this `redis.redis.keys('block::*', function (err, reply) { ... });` was losing the `this` value so when you set `this.blacklist`, you were setting it on some other object, not your actual blacklist object.  Change to an arrow function like this: `redis.redis.keys('block::*', (err, reply) => { ... });` or use `self` like you have in other places and the problem goes away.  I've corrected that issue in my answer.

Comment: Thanks, that did the trick , that also solved the issue that i couldn't call the this.logEvent .